# Online judge gives a Runtime error (NZEC)

Tags: java, algorithm

I´m trying to solve an algorithm problem. It's about generating prime numbers within a certain range. A virtual judge give me an NZEC error, specifically this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Codechef.main(Main.java:24)
```

In my pc this works, and I don't know what it should be.
Here's my code and the link of the judge.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    //precargar criba
    boolean[] criba = new boolean[100001];
    Arrays.fill(criba, true);
    for(int i=2; i<=criba.length;i++){
        for(int j=2;i*j<=100000;j++){
            criba[i*j]=false;
        }
    }
    BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String in;
    String t;
    long m,n;
    t=sc.readLine();
    int a=Integer.parseInt(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < a ; i++) {
        int k=0; int[] read=new int[2];
        in = sc.readLine();
        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(in);
        while(stk.hasMoreElements()){
            read[k]=Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
            k++;
        }
        m=read[0]; n=read[1];
        for(int j=(int) m; j<=n;j++){
            if(j==1 || j==2)continue;
            if(criba[j])System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

[Prime Generator SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify the delimiter in the statement.

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(in);
```

For example, If the delimiter is space character then you have to write:

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(in," ");
```

Comment: I read that if  you doesn't put the second parameter, the default is a blank space

Comment: Also you have to use while (stk.hasMoreTokens()) instead of while (stk.hasMoreElements())